# ReactComponent has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }' when using Route render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

When using:

```
<Route path={rootPath} exact render={props => <LoginLayout {...props} />} />
```

in typescript `LoginLayout` when prompts an error:

```
Type '{ history: History<PoorMansUnknown>; location: Location<PoorMansUnknown>; match: match<any>; staticContext?: StaticContext | undefined; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2559)
```

I tried to add:

```
const LoginLayout:FunctionComponent = (props: any) => { ... };

<Route path={rootPath} exact render={(props: any) => <LoginLayout {...props} />} />
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried:

```
const LoginLayout:FunctionComponent = (props: RouteComponentProps) => { ... };

<Route path={rootPath} exact render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => <LoginLayout {...props} />} />
```

And it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4):

It complains because you're passing props (`RouteComponentProps`) to component which doesn't expect to get them. To fix:

```
const LoginLayout: FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = () => {...};
```

Or even shorter:

```
const LoginLayout: FC<RouteComponentProps> = () => {...};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQoksuiEArjElIUqNeoxgBaKvyRQJAE2ot24aPDwI+AwtUgA7JHpgAFKmADOQytTgByBuknSBUW21ZoIe8-AAyEAHNgPV8UAE8tAC4CQgAeTRkdVQMjUwgLAD44AF44AAoAShys2PlgADcMlHN5WIB6Msr3JAAPTnhPb3gAQTAwHPyi7KycVjhxuAYYXig9OHitQTAUGAALbNpltdo4VsdJw3lZbJwwM0th+f8gkPCtXAA6J7P08zI6jPeMthJWIA)

Answer (score 1):

Extend 'RouterComponentProps' from 'react-router- and then use it in your functional component

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";

type Props = { component: FunctionComponent } & RouteComponentProps;

const LoginLayout: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {...};

export default LoginLayout;
```